# No write access to $HOME directory

Tags: permissions, linux-mint, home, kdm

While loading the KDE UI 
Linux boots to kdm, then I get a "bad" sound and black screen. Logs reveal the line in the title. I can <kbd>ctrl</kbd> - <kbd>alt</kbd> - <kbd>F4</kbd> just fine from there.

Tried:

- `chmod 755` on `/`,`/home`,`/home/kellogs`
- Verified I have no SElinux on the machine
- Removed samba from services that are launched at boot time

What else? (logs show `$HOME` as equivalent to /home/kellogs, so it knows where to go...). Oh, and, it used to work fine until I screwed around with samba...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3mGk.jpg

[image]

Comment: You did not chmod `/` to 755 did you? That is a very bad idea, never touch the permissions of `/`. Anyway, please show us the relevant error message and post the output of `ls -ld /home/kellogs`.

Comment: @terdon - incoming!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the screenshot you not only did a chmod 755 on /home/kellogs you also did a **chown 755** thus making that directory not owned by user kellogs.  So now you can't write to it.  You can see this where it says '755' before kellogs.

Fix it by running `chown kellogs /home/kellogs`.